# How to trigger the right mouse click event through JS?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to trigger the right mouse click event through JS.

Here is my test code:

```
            var obj = document.getElementById("testItem");
            var evObj = document.createEvent("MouseEvents",);
            evObj.initEvent('click', true, false);
            Object.defineProperty(evObj, "button", {
                value: 2,
                writable: false
            });
            Object.defineProperty(evObj, "buttons", {
                value: 2,
                writable: false
            });
            obj.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

I tried lots of methods, but they didn't work.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @toesslab I've tried these methods, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you work with the `CustomEvent`?

Comment: @toesslab Yes, I tried, but it didn't work and didn't report an error. `element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('contextmenu'));`